# insert into table select from table where columnname = xxx and columnname2 = yyy looping too many times

Tags: coldfusion, mariadb, lucee

I'll try to be as complete but concise as necessary. If I leave something out, please let me know.

I have a collection of activities and each activity is comprised of steps necessary to complete that given activity. Each step has a few additional components that go along with the step. If you were to look at this as a tree, it'd look like this:

`ACTIVITY
 -- STEP
 ---- COMPONENT`

Below is the dataset results of the component table.

[image]

I'm looking to write a mySQL insert/select statement that will allow me to copy the `ID = 84`. On the insert though, the ID value should inherit the new ID of the `ACTIVITY` (e.g. for example, let's go with 299) and the AID should inherit that of the `STEP` values (e.g. for this, let's go with 501,502,503,504,505,506).

I know what the mySQL statement would look like, that's not the problem. The problem I'm running into is how to write the loop so that I can pass in the new ID and the new AID values. The SID is the primary key (auto increment).

With the given dataset from above, I'd expect 6 new records to be inserted. Instead, I'm getting 9 so my loops are not looping correctly or I'm passing in the wrong data.

Here is the loop:

```
for (local.data.newAID in local.data.list_newAID){
    //  COPY SET
    for (local.data.origAID in local.data.list_existingAID){
        local.formDataStruct.origAID = local.data.origAID;
        variables.workoutDAO.makeCopyCoreSet(
            origID = local.dataStruct.ID,
            newID = local.dataStruct.newID,
            origAID = local.dataStruct.origAID,
            newAID = local.dataStruct.newAID
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the `makeCopyCoreSet` function:

```
INSERT INTO SET(ID, LID, AID)
SELECT
    :newID, LID, :newAID
FROM
    Set
WHERE ID = :origID AND AID = :origAID;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `LID`? And what version of MySQL?

Comment: LID is location as in locationID but that feature hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: And it looks like you are doing an INSERT for every loop. This can beat the heck out of your database.

Comment: Agreed. I would not be opposed to a single insert statement which I am also researching. I figured if I could get this to work, I can modify this to loop over the query insert statement after I gain some better understanding. I don't have a lot of experience with select/insert loops.

Comment: It's actually Maria 10.2.6.

Comment: @Shawn were you asking clarification questions or are you actively looking at my question? Thanks in advance either way.

Comment: Doing both. :-)

Comment: Great, I'm still hitting up google, too.

Comment: So you're looking to pass in 299 as the new Activity `ID` and copy the rows for `84`? How is `component` accounted for? It looks like there's just an `Activity` and a `Step`.

Comment: Never mind. This is the `component` table, so we're building and relating a Component, correct?

Comment: That is correct, this IS the component table.

Comment: What is the difference between SID 496, 501 and 502?

Comment: Nice catch. I removed the extra columns for brevity. That said, the omitted columns may or _may not_ contain the same values.

Comment: Something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8705ffdb902c6ff0a365677db54758a0  All you'd need to pass is the New ID and the ID that you want to copy. Then let the DB do the rest. Replace `299` with `:NewID` and `84` with `:OrigID`.

Comment: With your example, it looks like you are inserting 9 records but it should only be 6 records (duplicating the existing records). This is the problem I ran into as well, I keep getting 9 inserts. I understand why this is happening but cant wrap my head around what to do about it LOL.

Comment: It should only be inserting the new records. There are the 9 originals (including the dupes I added to demonstrate DISTINCT) and then 6 new records for `NewID` 299.

Comment: If you want to see what was inserted, just query for the New ID.

Comment: OOOhhhh, I didn't click on the elipses to see the expanded result set on the second query (referring to your dbfiddle)

Comment: Yeah, I hate when it does that. I love dbfiddle.uk, but that bites me all the time. :-S

Comment: This.Solution.Is.Awesome! Turns out to be a query issue and I was looking at CF/Lucee as the culprit. Thank you! Share your fiddle as the answer so I can accept it at your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to copy one of our Activities, so we want to pass the ID we want to copy and the ID we want to be the new ID (unless we have another way to determine it.

```
variables.workoutDAO.NEW_makeCopyCoreSet(
            origID = local.dataStruct.ID,
            newID = local.dataStruct.newID
        );
```

And then in our `NEW_makeCopyCoreSet()` function (a CF function), we have the query:

> ```
> INSERT INTO component (ID, LID, AID)
> SELECT DISTINCT :newID, LID, AID 
> FROM component
> WHERE ID = :origID
> ```

To see it in action (from the SQL side):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ba4328dca3327814a7dc18fea284ead8

First we set up our base data.

> ```
> /* SETUP 1 */
> CREATE TABLE component ( ID int, LID int, AID int, SID int UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT)
>
> /* SETUP 2 */
> INSERT INTO component (ID, LID, AID)
> SELECT 84,0,432 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,433 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,434 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,435 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,435 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,435 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,435 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,436 UNION ALL
> SELECT 84,0,437
>
> /* What's in the original? */
> SELECT * FROM component
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | LID | AID | SID
> -: | --: | --: | --:
> 84 |   0 | 432 |   1
> 84 |   0 | 433 |   2
> 84 |   0 | 434 |   3
> 84 |   0 | 435 |   4
> 84 |   0 | 435 |   5
> 84 |   0 | 435 |   6
> 84 |   0 | 435 |   7
> 84 |   0 | 436 |   8
> 84 |   0 | 437 |   9
> ```

Then we copy an existing ID to a new ID.

> ```
> /* Copy an ID. */
> INSERT INTO component (ID, LID, AID)
> SELECT DISTINCT 299, LID, AID 
> FROM component
> WHERE ID = 84
>
> /* What's in the table for the new ID? */
> SELECT * FROM component WHERE ID = 299
> ```
>
> ```
>  ID | LID | AID | SID
> --: | --: | --: | --:
> 299 |   0 | 432 |  16
> 299 |   0 | 433 |  17
> 299 |   0 | 434 |  18
> 299 |   0 | 435 |  19
> 299 |   0 | 436 |  20
> 299 |   0 | 437 |  21
> ```

Comment: Hey Shawn, I encountered an issue. Looks like we/I totally forgot about the new AID values of 501,502,503,504,505,506.The ID portion works but how do I also loop over the new AID values such that 501 corresponds to 432, 502 corresponds to 433 and so on?

Comment: You said that SID was an auto_number. Can you take a step back and define what each of those columns stand for? And is that all there is in that table, or are there other columns that further define a difference between SID numbers? What you are calling for now doesn't match your original display. I'm not sure how your numbers line up. I know you can't be overly explicit to protect your data, but I need to know the basics of how you are determining your `component` table. Can you also provide a simple example of your Steps and Activities tables? What do you mean by "501 corresponds to 432"?

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem. It's a bit complicated to write in 500 chars or less but it's working perfectly now, thank you for getting me going in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got squared away.